# Why are so few answers accepted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Of the questions listed, many don't have accepted answers -- even if there are many and/or good answers. I know that often software recommendations can be a grey zone, and it is hard (if not impossible) to find a definite answer. Still, I think that, if questions have answers that fit the asked requirements well, an answer should be accepted, so that people can see that there is a good program, and so that we don't turn into a beta with a million questions and no accepted answers.

Any other thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Also see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/203/356

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It takes time to test a recommendation.** This is exactly why most paid products have a trial period. You can't just jump to conclusions and think "oh this has a lot of upvotes, this *is* the product I'm going to use." No, that's going to be your *starting point*. You'll probably try that one out first, and then maybe try some of the others to see which one you actually like more. Picking software is not like picking apples - it takes time and effort to find the perfect tool. No one should be expecting quick accepts on a site like this. I'd actually encourage users to wait a day or so, *maybe even weeks*, before accepting an answer as "the best answer" - so that they have some time to really get into the tool and confirm that, yes, this product solves all my problems.

Also, **some of these questions are going to be examples questions.** Face it, we're in a private beta phase. Some will be posted as templates to try and get the site running. That means that some of the authors aren't *actually* looking for an answer, but just posting something that *someone might be looking for in the future*. Thus, as they gather answers, they don't really have the ability to "accept a best answer" because none of the answers helped them, personally.

Answer (score 15):

If I ask a question on SE (any site), I always wait a few days for more/better answer. Especially on this site, you don't know how many answers you will get. Any subsequent recommendation can be the best. By not accepting an answer yet, you also make clear that you are open for more possible answers. And, with respect to software recommendations, it my take some time to test all of the recommendations, and select one.

Comment: +1, but not accepted yet :D

Comment: @MadTux You need more time? ;)